# ILogger (ASP.NET Core) Log is called even IsEnabled return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to understand the purpose of [IsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_IsEnabled_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LogLevel_) method in ILogger interface.
I would expect that method is automatically called every time something can be log, but method Log is called no mater what returned IsEnabled.

Should I check IsEnabled inside Log method?

```
    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel >= this.level;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled(logLevel))   //it seams that this is required ????
        {
            string s = formatter(state, exception);
            string formatted = s.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n                          ");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-15} {1,-5} - {2}", logLevel, eventId, formatted));
        }
    }
```

Then what is the purpose and who(why) calls IsEnabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless Microsoft changed it, yes you are supposed to call `IsEnabled` yourself.

The reasoning is that if the API would call IsEnabled, and then the user's code calls IsEnabled, that would double the calls per log operation and would hit performance more than it helps eventually.

Also, the logging framework would always respect filters and min log level before writing something to the log sinks. Meaning, if you always call `LogDebug` for example and `Information` is your configured minimum log level, the debug messages will not appear in the log.

But! the code to call `LogDebug` and filtering gets excecuted if you do not check for `logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug)` and run the code only if necessary.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I feel the need to comment that it seems odd to have the `ILogger` interface enforce the creation of an `IsEnabled` method that it does not expect to ever be called (except by your own code, if you want to).  Why is it part of the interface?  If I need an `IsEnabled` method, I can make one even if it is not part of the interface.  (There seems to be no reason that `IsEnabled` is part of the `ILogger` interface.)

Answer (score 12):

`IsEnabled` is especially important when you pass parameters.

**Without IsEnabled**

```
logger.LogDebug("My debug message with {payload}", Serialize(myPayload));
```

In this case, myPayload is serialized on EVERY call to `LogDebug` regardless of your log level settings. This could be an unnecessary hit in a production environment, and potentially lead to unexpected errors. What if Serialize method fails due to unexpected data?

**With IsEnabled**

```
if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
{
    logger.LogDebug("My debug message with {payload}", Serialize(myPayload));
}
```

In this case, myPayload is only serialized when `LogDebug` is enabled in your settings.

**Balanced approach**

Personally, I skip `IsEnabled` checks with "constant text" calls to Log() methods (e.g., `logger.LogDebug("constant string")`), and only test `IsEnabled` when I need to log with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6, you can use [logger delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/high-performance-logging) to avoid explicitly calling the `IsEnabled` method, since it is automatically done.

This approach allows you to have additional benefits since the formatter is created once and is optimized for high volume calls.

Comment: I regard this as the new best option as of now. I remember old days where other log provides accepted an action and it was only evaluated when the log level matched. This appears to be MS implementation of this pattern.