# Why is IsEnabled part of the ILogger Interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, interface

The ILogger interface has a required method of [`IsEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.isenabled?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).  I am struggling to understand the purpose of that method in the interface.  (Important note: I am not wondering about an implementing class, just the interface.)

It does not seem to be called by .Net Core during normal logging.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586621/16241) seems to indicate that it is there for the developer to use when deciding to log.

But that does not make sense.  As the developer I can make any method I need in the class that implements the ILogger interface in order to decide if I want to log or not.  If a class implementing the interface does not need to provide an IsEnabled, it does not make sense to force all implementors to make it.

What is the purpose of is `IsEnabled` in the `ILogger` Interface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some times it might be costly to compute some arguments that are passed. Hence, the caller can filter out the work as needed:

```
if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
{
     logger.LogDebug("The message: {value}", DoSomethingCostlyHere());
}
```

Another common pattern is to put more details, such as PII or other sensitive data, into debug messages that wouldn't be surfaced in production:

```
if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
{
     logger.LogDebug("'{username}' logged in", username);
}
else 
{
     logger.LogInformation("User logged in");
}
```

Other logging frameworks have this too: [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_ILoggerBase_IsEnabled.htm), [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/8f2263cb9e97146d9e180783dba601d9902eeeaf/src/Serilog/ILogger.cs#L358), [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Core_ILogger_IsEnabledFor.htm), etc.